# Insert a custom class into Bootstrap Classloader into java.base module

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I'm trying to insert my custom class to Bootstrap Classloader to be able to call `sun.nio.ch.IOUtil#fdVal(FileDescriptor)` to get the value of the FileDescriptor and use it in my Advice (I wrapped `sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl`)

I successfully inserted my `pbouda.agents.core.Utils` into the bootstrap classloader.

```
public abstract class Utils {

    public static final int ERROR_FD_VALUE = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    private static Method FD_VALUE_METHOD;

    static {
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("sun.nio.ch.IOUtil");
            FD_VALUE_METHOD = clazz.getMethod("fdVal", FileDescriptor.class);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static int fdVal(FileDescriptor fd) {
        if (FD_VALUE_METHOD != null) {
            try {
                return (int) FD_VALUE_METHOD.invoke(null, fd);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return ERROR_FD_VALUE;
    }
}
```

using

```
public abstract class UtilsInitializer {

    private static boolean INITIALIZED = false;

    public static synchronized void initialize() {
        if (!INITIALIZED) {
            TypePool typePool = TypePool.Default.ofSystemLoader();

            Map<TypeDescription, byte[]> types = new ByteBuddy()
                    .redefine(
                            typePool.describe("pbouda.agents.core.Utils").resolve(),
                            ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.ofSystemLoader())
                    .make()
                    .getAllTypes();

            ClassInjector.UsingUnsafe.ofBootLoader()
                    .inject(types);

            INITIALIZED = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I've proved it!

```
~ jcmd 281091 VM.classloaders show-classes                                                                                         [21/09/21|11:50AM]
281091:
+-- <bootstrap>
     |     
     |               Classes: java.lang.Object
     |                        [Ljava.lang.Object;
     |                        [[Ljava.lang.Object;
     |                        java.io.Serializable
...
     |                        pbouda.agents.core.Utils
     |                        (1522 classes)
     |     
     |        Hidden Classes: java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/0x0000000800d89c00
     |                        java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/0x0000000800d89800
```

Unfortunately, it's in a different module of course :(

```
     java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class pbouda.agents.core.Utils cannot access class sun.nio.ch.IOUtil 
     (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @7e928e2f
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:392)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:674)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:560)
      
        at pbouda.agents.core.Utils.fdVal(Utils.java:26)

      at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.open(FileChannelImpl.java:151)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixChannelFactory.newFileChannel(UnixChannelFactory.java:134)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixChannelFactory.newFileChannel(UnixChannelFactory.java:146)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:217)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:484)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:228)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter(Files.java:3008)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter(Files.java:3056)
        at pbouda.agents.file.FileTest.bufferedWriter(FileTest.java:38)
```

Do you know how to inject it into `java.base` to avoid running the program with `add-opens` ?

Answer (score 1):

Any module predeclares its packages. In order to add something to *java.base*, you must add a class to a package that *java.base* already contains such as *java.lang*.

This is no longer possible using `Instrumentation.appendToBootSearchPath` as the packages of *java.base* are only directed to the *jmod* in question. Instead, you can open modules, including *java.base* by using the new `modifyModule` API.

If you really wanted to inject classes, this is still possible using `Unsafe`. Byte Buddy offers a factory for this in correspondance with its `AgentBuilder`. [Have a look at `ClassInjector.UsingUnsafe.Factory`](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/master/byte-buddy-dep/src/main/java/net/bytebuddy/dynamic/loading/ClassInjector.java#L2140) which offers to create such an injector. The `Instrumentation` instance is required to fall back to the JDKs internal `Ùnsafe` API after the semi-public one was removed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rafael!

I changed the package `pbouda.agents.core.Utils` -> `sun.nio.ch.Utils`

And changed the initializer and it works!!
(Nasty but it's a good start for implementing a searcher of Leaked Descriptors :)

```
public abstract class UtilsInitializer {

    private static boolean INITIALIZED = false;

    public static synchronized void initialize(Instrumentation inst) {
        if (!INITIALIZED) {
            TypePool typePool = TypePool.Default.ofSystemLoader();

            Map<TypeDescription, byte[]> types = new ByteBuddy()
                    .redefine(
                            typePool.describe("sun.nio.ch.Utils").resolve(),
                            ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.ofSystemLoader())
                    .make()
                    .getAllTypes();

            ClassInjector.UsingUnsafe.ofBootLoader()
                    .inject(types);

            INITIALIZED = true;
        }
    }
}
```